# i want to measure the distance between nosetip and tip of index finger using facemesh vertices

Tags: python, computer-vision, coordinates, mediapipe, vertices

I have put facemesh and handmesh in a single frame real-time.

I've been trying to get the coordinates of each of the facemesh vertices but having trouble.

I was able to print out the whole coordinates through

```
print (results.multi_face_landmarks[0])
```

but it seems to be containing the coordinates of whole vertices.

I would like to for instance get only the coordinates of the tip of the nose, which is vertices 4 out of 478 vertices.

In the future i want to measure the distance of the point and the tip of index finger to alert user of habitually touching their nose.

**Can't find out if the whole coordinates are saved and loaded in a form of table or list.

please help me out on how to find the coordinate.**

here is my code so far. i have imported math to in the future calculate distance.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mediapipe as mp


#################################################################
import math

def calculate_distance(point1, point2):
    x1, y1, z1 = point1
    x2, y2, z2 = point2
    
    distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 + (z2 - z1)**2)
    return distance
##################################################################

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mpFaceMesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh
mpHands = mp.solutions.hands

faceMesh = mpFaceMesh.FaceMesh(max_num_faces=2)
handsMesh = mpHands.Hands(max_num_hands=2)

drawSpecFace = mpDraw.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=1)
drawSpecHands = mpDraw.DrawingSpec(thickness=1, circle_radius=1)

both_detected = False  # Initialize detection flag


while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    results = faceMesh.process(imgRGB)
    if results.multi_face_landmarks:
        for faceLms in results.multi_face_landmarks:
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, faceLms, mpFaceMesh.FACEMESH_CONTOURS, drawSpecFace, drawSpecFace)

            face = results.multi_face_landmarks[0]; 


    results2 = handsMesh.process(imgRGB)
    if results2.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results2.multi_hand_landmarks:
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS, drawSpecHands, drawSpecHands)

    # Check if both face and hands are detected
    if results.multi_face_landmarks and results2.multi_hand_landmarks:
        both_detected = True
        cv2.putText(img, "Why Are Your Hands Near Face?", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (34,139,34), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    else:
        both_detected = False




    print (results.multi_face_landmarks[0])





    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And this is my result so far:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself.

```
results.multi_face_landmarks[0]
```

parse out the result of the whole coordinates.

in order to get a certain coordination of vertices,

I just had to do this.

```
results.multi_face_landmarks[0].landmark[x]
```

x is the vertice number you can find on face mesh mapping image.